# BizTalk: process unrelated messages in a given order

Tags: design-patterns, process, biztalk

I am receiving messages from an external system.
There are three message types, each representing a type of entity, and each message will contain a verb (create,update,delete)
This is represented as below.

Entity A (CUD)
Entity B (CUD)
Entity C (U)

Entity B have a relationship to entity A meaning that entity A must be created before entity B can be created/updated.
Enitity C have a relationship to entity B meaning that entity B must be created before entity C can be updated.

The messages will be used to update two other external systems.
The messages may be received out of order meaning that entity B may be received before entity A.

I am struggling to find a good pattern to ensure that message entities are processed in the correct order.
I would prefer not to use a database or file system if possible.
Any suggestions as to how to solve this are more than welcome.

Answer (score 4):

First, push back on the source system.  If there is a genuine order to the messages, then they really need to support that.  If they can't or refuse, then you heed to inform your management that you have to spend extra time to accommodate their lack of compliance for the business requirements.

Having said that, you can probably achieve this using a Parallel Convoy so long as there is a definitive way to relate the incoming messages, AccountID or some such.

Even if B or C Activates the Convoy Orchestration, it will wait for A to continue processing.  Then you can process the messages in any order you want.

One thing to remember, you should put each Receive Shape in a Scope with a Timeout, otherwise, it A or B/C get 'lost', the Orchestration will wait forever.  If the timeout fires, you can send an Alert.

Here is an example of a Parallel Convoy: [Parallel Convoy in BizTalk example](http://biztalkvillage.blogspot.com/2013/01/parallel-convoy-in-biztalk-example.html)

There are many others you can find through Bing or Google.